# Nested Selects with values coming from the server with angularjs are empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have two nested Selects representing state and city in a form. Everything works fine when the user selects and saves the form but when the saved data comes from the server, the second Select does not show the value of the corresponding variable despite being with the correct value. Does anyone know where this my fault? Any help is greatly appreciated!

> HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="selectState" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select id="selectState" class="form-control" ng-model="selected_state">
      <option disable value="">Escolha um estado... </option>
      <option ng-selected="selected_state == state.id" ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.id}}" >{{state.description}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="selectCity" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cidade</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select id="selectCity" class="form-control" ng-model="selected_city" >
      <option disable value="">Escolha uma cidade... </option>
      <option id="optionCity" ng-selected="selected_city == city.id" ng-repeat="city in cities" value="{{city.id}}" >{{city.description}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Function that updates the nested Selects

```
$scope.$watch('selected_state', function(newVal) {
    if (newVal) load_cities_by_state($http, $scope, $cookies, $scope.selected_state, $cookieStore);
});
```

> Function called by the editing method including the bearing which is
>   required for Selects

```
function detail_office($http, $scope, $cookies, $cookieStore, $timeout){
    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: URL,
        headers: {
            'x-csrftoken' : $cookies.get('csrftoken'),
            'authorization': getAuthorizationToken($cookieStore)
        }
    }
    $http(req).then(function(response) {
        $scope.editingOffice = true;
        $scope.start_office = new Date(response.data.start);
        if (response.data.end != null){
            $scope.end_office = new Date(response.data.end);
        }
        $scope.selected_state = response.data.state;
        $scope.selected_office=response.data.office_type;
        $scope.selected_city = response.data.city;
        $scope.description_office = response.data.description;
        $scope.showOfficeRegister = true;
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.showOfficeRegister = false;
        build_error_message($scope, response, $timeout)
    });
};
```

Thank's

Comment: _but when the saved data comes from the server, the second Select does not show the value of the corresponding variable despite being with the correct value_ - the data that is coming from the server is retrieved via an ajax request I assume? Could you clarify _the value of the corresponding variable despite being with the correct value_?

Comment: Zack, the value **selected_city** is an integer that is the city id

Comment: Please add example data in `states` and `cities` variables. Also provide an example of response that is retrieved from the API.